# jquery selector not working in document.ready with IE8 on td with custom attribute (knockoutjs)

Tags: jquery, html, selector, knockout.js

I can't get jquery to select elements by id or class when those elements have custom attributes on them... (in this case, the elements are td tags with attribute "data-bind" - am using knockoutJS)

If I select by tag, e.g. `$("table tr")` , it works fine.  It also works if I add `runat="server"` to the table tag, and then change the selector to `$("#<%=tblTimslips.ClientID%>")`, but if I do that, then knockout doesn't recognize the table anymore.

Edit:  I added another selector (the uncommented one in the javascript below), which succesfully grabs the TRs in the THEAD tag, but not the ones in the TBODY tag....  ??

Why won't it select by ID or class?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .highlight2
    {
        background-color: #0000ee;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadClient();
        //$(".TimeslipsGrid tr").hover(function () { 
        // above selector by class doesn't work, nor does the following by id:
        // $("#tblTimeslips").hover(function(){     
        //  however, the following selector WILL work on all tr on the page, including my targets in #tblTimeslip:
        // $("table tr").hover(function(){
        // the following selector works, but ONLY FOR THE TR CONTAINED IN THEAD..
        //  changing it to "#tblTimeslips tbody tr" doesn't help, either..
        $("#tblTimeslips tr").hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("highlight2");
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight2");
        })
</script>

<table id="tblTimeslips" class="TimeslipsGrid">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th><th>Dur</th><th>File</th><th>Task/Activity</th><th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: timeslips">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: TimeString"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: DurationString"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: FileNumber"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: TaskActivityAbbrText"></td>
        <td><img data-bind="attr: { src: NoteIconPath }" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's what the #tblTimeslips html looks like after knockout is done with it.  I still can't see the problem.

```
<table class="TimeslipsGrid" id="tblTimeslips">
<THEAD>
<TR jQuery17108028844206682706="72">
<TH>Time</TH>
<TH>Dur</TH>
<TH>File</TH>
<TH>Task/Activity</TH>
<TH>Note</TH></TR></THEAD>
<TBODY data-bind="foreach: timeslips" __ko__1328033964035="ko1">
<TR jQuery17108028844206682706="73" __ko__1328033964035="ko2">
<TD data-bind="text: TimeString" __ko__1328033964035="ko3">00:00<BR>06:23 AM</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: DurationString" __ko__1328033964035="ko4">6.38</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: FileNumber" __ko__1328033964035="ko5">9-12632-555</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: TaskActivityAbbrText" __ko__1328033964035="ko6">Admin | Agnt Suprvsn</TD>
<TD><IMG src="../Images/Homepage/note_full_16.png" data-bind="attr: { src: NoteIconPath }" __ko__1328033964035="ko7"></TD></TR>
<TR jQuery17108028844206682706="73" __ko__1328033964035="ko8">
<TD data-bind="text: TimeString" __ko__1328033964035="ko9">06:23<BR>06:28 AM</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: DurationString" __ko__1328033964035="ko10">0.08</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: FileNumber" __ko__1328033964035="ko11">9-12601-7</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: TaskActivityAbbrText" __ko__1328033964035="ko12">Admin | PTOW</TD>
<TD><IMG src="../Images/Homepage/note_full_16.png" data-bind="attr: { src: NoteIconPath }" __ko__1328033964035="ko13"></TD></TR>
<TR jQuery17108028844206682706="73" __ko__1328033964035="ko14">
<TD data-bind="text: TimeString" __ko__1328033964035="ko15">06:28<BR>08:28 AM</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: DurationString" __ko__1328033964035="ko16">2</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: FileNumber" __ko__1328033964035="ko17">(no timeslip)</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: TaskActivityAbbrText" __ko__1328033964035="ko18">(none)</TD>
<TD><IMG src="../Images/Homepage/note_empty_16.png" data-bind="attr: { src: NoteIconPath }" __ko__1328033964035="ko19"></TD></TR>
<TR jQuery17108028844206682706="73" __ko__1328033964035="ko20">
<TD data-bind="text: TimeString" __ko__1328033964035="ko21">08:28<BR>09:28 AM</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: DurationString" __ko__1328033964035="ko22">1</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: FileNumber" __ko__1328033964035="ko23">9-12632-553</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: TaskActivityAbbrText" __ko__1328033964035="ko24">T-A | KM</TD>
<TD><IMG src="../Images/Homepage/note_full_16.png" data-bind="attr: { src: NoteIconPath }" __ko__1328033964035="ko25"></TD></TR>
<TR jQuery17108028844206682706="73" __ko__1328033964035="ko26">
<TD data-bind="text: TimeString" __ko__1328033964035="ko27">09:28<BR>11:01 AM</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: DurationString" __ko__1328033964035="ko28">1.55</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: FileNumber" __ko__1328033964035="ko29">(no timeslip)</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: TaskActivityAbbrText" __ko__1328033964035="ko30">(none)</TD>
<TD><IMG src="../Images/Homepage/note_empty_16.png" data-bind="attr: { src: NoteIconPath }" __ko__1328033964035="ko31"></TD></TR>
<TR jQuery17108028844206682706="73" __ko__1328033964035="ko32">
<TD data-bind="text: TimeString" __ko__1328033964035="ko33">11:01<BR>10:00 PM</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: DurationString" __ko__1328033964035="ko34">10.98</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: FileNumber" __ko__1328033964035="ko35">2-9999-1</TD>
<TD data-bind="text: TaskActivityAbbrText" __ko__1328033964035="ko36">ATL | Doc Conv &amp;DE</TD>
<TD><IMG src="../Images/Homepage/note_full_16.png" data-bind="attr: { src: NoteIconPath }" __ko__1328033964035="ko37"></TD></TR></TBODY>
</table>
```

Comment: Make sure your selectors match in JS and CSS. `.TimeslipsGrid tr.highlight2` isn't the same thing as `.highlight2 tr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css-selector `.highlight2 tr{}` should be `.highlight2{}` (or `tr.highlight2{}`) , otherwise the selector won't match. Has nothing to do with faulty jquery;)

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter either way. Anyway, I changed it to .highlight2{} but it doesn't help. Please note that when I use $("#tblTimeslips tr"), the tr in the thead highlights successfully, but the TRs in the tbody do not.  Also, I don't think it's faulty jquery... according to my research, it seems to have something to do with the way IE8 does not recognize the custom data-bind attribute on the TD?

Comment: well, I guess it's an issue with knockout then? Jquery has no problem with custom attributes (on normal browsers^.^).

Comment: perhaps selecting the tds directly by a class might help?

Comment: Yeah... on normal browsers, that's what I'm worried about.  Anyway, I'm adding the rendered html to my question, in case it helps answer it...

Comment: my quick-guess would be that ie8 has problems with attributes starting with an underscore

Comment: Could be... I'll search that. In the meantime, I tried your suggestion about selecting trs or tds directly using a class, but it doesn't work. e.g. if I use the selector $("tr.tkTr") for my hover, and change the markup to <tbody data-bind="foreach: timeslips">
    <tr class="tkTr">    .... it still doesn't work.

Comment: Argghh... StackOverflow... don't suggest I "automatically move this discussion to chat", and then when I try to do it, tell me I don't have enough reputation to chat. ...  NO I don't want to do that.  Stop making rules that only the privileged can follow.

Comment: Can you influence knockouts naming conventions? If possible, remove the underscores and try again.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out...  the line loadClient(); is what applies the knockout bindings, by calling a $.ajax, which has a success callback...  inside that success callback is where I have ko.applyBindings.   Since it's a callback, it doesn't get called right away I guess...  The solution was to move my selector from $(document).ready to the success callback, and everything worked.

Comment: Incidentally, StackOverflow is really ticking me off...  every time I use it and want to do anything it says I don't have enough reputation.  I can't even answer my own question, it says I have to wait six hours.  By then, I'll have completely forgotten about this and will be struggling with the next problem.  That means this question will probably never be marked as answered, even though it is answered..

Comment: well, at least you figured it out;)

Comment: Was it me that marked this as answered? It's misleading, because the first response wasn't the actual solution, yet it has a big green checkmark next to it. The solution is in the comments. I did try to add the real solution as another 'Answer' but StackOverflow wouldn't let me. (Insufficient reputation, of course.) It's a good thing stackoverflow already has such a good userbase, because otherwise I wouldn't be using it. There's nothing worse than a system that tells you to do something a certain way, and then when you try to do precisely what it asks, it says you don't have permission.